# How do I reverse selected lines order in Vim?

Tags: vim, editing, text-editors, text-editing

For example, if I have four lines as follows:

> the first line 
>   the second line 
>   the third line 
>   the fourth line

I want to reverse them to

> the fourth line 
>   the third line 
>   the second line 
>   the first line

How could I do this in Vim?

Comment: Duplicate on [SO]: [How to flip a visual selection in vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5561249/2157640)

Comment: Related: [Reverse all lines @ Vim Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_all_lines)

Comment: `:command! -bar -range=% Reverse <line1>,<line2>global/^/m<line1>-1` https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2107/10254

Answer (score 143, accepted):

To reverse all the lines in a file,

```
:global/^/move 0
```

Abbreviated:

```
:g/^/m0
```

For an [explanation](https://vimhelp.org/usr_12.txt.html#12.4) see

```
:help 12.4
```

which also shows how to reverse just a range of lines.

Comment: Great tip on the exact help section! To summarize: 1. set a marker at the last line you want reverse (I name the marker 'a' using `ma`), 2. move cursor to the first line of the block, 3. type `:'a,.g/^/m 'a`

Comment: [`:help 12.4`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_12.html#12.4).

Answer (score 121):

Select the desired lines, hit `!`, and in the resulting prompt pipe the lines through `tac` a la `:'<,'>!tac`.  See `man tac` for more details.

Comment: To select the lines, use `shift+v` to enter visual line mode, then `j` to add lines to the selection.

Comment: I can confirm that this works in windows with `gvim`, as well! Otherwise, you have to use absolute line numbers (maybe you can use relative, but you have to be careful) with the `:g/^/m0` (which is also really hard to remember) ... So, essentially, tac should be with vim no matter what platform you're on, BUT it's not 100% vimscript, BUT who cares :P

Comment: tac isn't fully-native vim handling, but, the 'm'ove command takes a line number and that's not always reasonable. I often use a mark as part of a range, so `:.,'a!tac` works with minimal effort.

Comment: After using `shift+v`, you can use `}` to reach up to the next paragraph, or empty vertical space. Also, `man tac: concatenate and print files in reverse`.

Comment: This is so money!!!

Comment: (Hitting `!` autofills `:'<'>!` when there is a selection.)

Comment: Also great with `vip` to select the current paragraph, followed by `!` which automatically inserts `:'<,'>!` followed by `tac`. In short what you end up tipping to reverse the current paragraph is `vip!tac`.

Answer (score 46):

On Mac OS X, `tac` does not exist, but you can use `tail -r` to the same effect:

```
:%!tail -r
```

This also works nicely for visual mode:

```
:'<,'>!tail -r
```

Excerpt from `tail(1)`'s manpage:

> The -r option causes the input to be displayed in reverse order, by
>   line.  Additionally, this option changes the meaning of the -b, -c and
>   -n options.  When the -r option is specified, these options specify the number of bytes, lines or 512-byte blocks to display, instead of
>   the bytes, lines or blocks from the beginning or end of the input from
>   which to begin the display.  **The default for the -r option is to
>   display all of the input.**

Comment: Excellent! So to provide 'tac' under OS X: `alias tac='tail -r'`

Comment: You can also `brew install coreutils` and use `gtac`.

Comment: Genius. Never thought of using ! commands for this type of visual line manipulation.

Comment: Most elegant one of all!

Comment: It's a pity `-r` isn't a valid option for GNU `tail`, otherwise we'd have one nice, concise solution that works on Macs and Linux at least.

Answer (score 8):

For those more comfortable with Visual mode:
 1. Identify the line number above the selection you want flipped using `:set nu`.
 2. `Shift-V` to highlight selection you want flipped (visual mode).
 3. `:g/^/m <Line number from step 1>`.

Note that in visual mode it will automatically show up as
    `:'<,'>g/^/m <Line number>` when you type in the command from 3.

This command works by moving the selection one line at a time into the line number that you give it. When the second item gets pushed into the line number given, it pushes the first down to line number + 1. Then the third pushes the first and second down and so on until the entire list has been pushed into the single line number resulting in a reverse ordered list.

Comment: You can use the `'<` instead of entering the line number manually. Just start the selection one line earlier and execute `:'<,'>g/^/m'<`.

Answer (score 7):

A command `:Rev[erse]` and optional mappings for your `vimrc`, so you don't have to remember and perform the non-obvious steps of this recipe:

```
" Reverse the lines of the whole file or a visually highlighted block.
    " :Rev is a shorter prefix you can use.
    " Adapted from http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/34305
command! -nargs=0 -bar -range=% Reverse
    \       let save_mark_t = getpos("'t")
    \<bar>      <line2>kt
    \<bar>      exe "<line1>,<line2>g/^/m't"
    \<bar>  call setpos("'t", save_mark_t)

nmap <Leader>r :Reverse<CR>
xmap <Leader>r :Reverse<CR>
```

(`:xmap` maps for Visual but not Select mode, as `:help mapmode-x` advises for mapping printable characters.)

<sub>(Based on: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/34305 )</sub>

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO. Most generally useful and I don't have to remember `:'<,'>g/^/m'<` :)

Comment: @Eliot, thanks! :)  (I added a bit of 'bonus content'. ;) )

Comment: How can I say selection start -1 in this case? Because the move starts at this point.

Comment: @SergioAraujo: Is something like `:-1,+1Rev` what you are looking for?  Know that you can visually select the range you want to reverse, e.g.: `V7j:Rev`.  If that doesn’t answer your question, I haven’t understood it, so you’d need to elaborate or rephrase it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Let' say you are at the line 3, hence we have a range 3 to 6. Just type.

```
:3,6g/^/m2
```

Comment: You can leave the current line’s number implicit:  With the cursor on your range’s first line, you can shorten to `:,6g/^/m2`;  or when on the range’s last line: `:3,g/^/m2`;  and `:3,6g/^/m2` works from anywhere in the file.